# Questions about the way out, ref, and [Out] behave in unmanaged delegate signatures

Tags: c#, .net, interop

I happen to use heavy Interoperability features in some of my C# programs. In this process, I have found some odd behavior and limits to the out, ref, and [Out] options that exist. I also have found some work around to some of the limitations.

Given this, I would like to ask about why the examples given below behave the way they do. It would be nice to not have to use such tricks to work-around the limitation of using out or ref in params object[] signatures (or any params, actually). I am sure it is more likely than not there is good enough reason to not allow it even though the given work around's exist as shown below.

I will try to illustrate the behavior I refer to in the pseudo code below, comments explain most of what goes on. Feel free to ask me more specifics.

Incase it is not clear what my question is: Why am I not allowed to use out/ref tags in my parameters for my method, despite it being totally possible and working just fine if the "tricks" below are applied.

```
class InteropExamples {
    /* note: these delegates fields must be kept alive in a real class too,
       or else GC can collect them.
    */

    // One method has out, the other [Out] attribute (in order, A out, B [Out])
    readonly TryGetLocationA _tryGetLocationA;
    readonly TryGetLocationB _tryGetLocationB;

    // One method has ref IntPtr, the other IntPtr[] (in order, A ref IntPtr, B IntPtr[])
    readonly IsEntityValidA _isEntityValidA;
    readonly IsEntityValidB _isEntityValidB;

    readonly int _mainThreadID;

    public bool InvokeRequired => GetCurrentThreadId() != _mainThreadID;

    public InteropExamples() {
        var addressOne = IntPtr.Zero; // real address of the func here of course.
        var addressTwo = IntPtr.Zero; // real address of the func here of course.

        _tryGetLocationA =
            Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(addressOne, typeof(TryGetLocationA)) as TryGetLocationA;
        _tryGetLocationB =
            Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(addressOne, typeof(TryGetLocationB)) as TryGetLocationB;

        _isEntityValidA =
            Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(addressTwo, typeof(IsEntityValidA)) as IsEntityValidA;
        _isEntityValidB =
            Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(addressTwo, typeof(IsEntityValidB)) as IsEntityValidB;

        _mainThreadID = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads[0].Id;
    }


    // This way works as expected with no limits.
    // delegate void TryGetLocationA(IntPtr address, out Vector3 result);   
    public Vector3 GetLocationA(IntPtr address) {
        Vector3 location;
        // note: Invoke(_tryGetLocationA, address, out location) is not possible here.
        _tryGetLocationA(address, out location);
        return location;
    }

    // In this example, we use a trick to be able to 
    // use the out despite using params object[] args
    // not allowing you to pass out or ref.
    // delegate void TryGetLocationB(IntPtr address, [Out] Vector3[] result);   
    public Vector3 GetLocationB(IntPtr address) {
        // note: if your delegate signature - 
        // has out and not the attribute [Out]
        // it will fail.
        var location = new Vector3[1];
        // The result gets passed to the first index of the array, 0.
        // Use our special invoke method with params object[] thus not allowing - 
        // us to use out directly like in example A.
        Invoke(_tryGetLocationB, address, location);
        return location[0];
    }

    // This way works fine and as expected.
    public bool IsEntityValid_A(IntPtr entityAddress) {
        // note:  (bool) Invoke(_isEntityValidA, ref entityAddress) is not valid here.
        return _isEntityValidA(ref entityAddress);
    }

    public bool IsEntityValid_B(IntPtr entityAddress) {
        // note: no ref tag needed here, unlike the [Out] example.
        // The array trick allows us to once again by pass the limit -
        // of not being able to use ref in params object[] (or params of any kind).
        var isEntityValid = (bool) Invoke(_isEntityValidB, new[] {entityAddress});
        return isEntityValid;
    }


    // An example of why we might want to invoke unmanaged funcs with -
    // a generic method using params[] object[] args, which sadly -
    // with out using tricks will not allow use of out/ref signatures.
    // Work arounds exist and shown in this class.
    object Invoke<T>(T target, params object[] args) where T : class {
        var targetDelegate = target as Delegate;
        if (targetDelegate == null) {
            throw new ArgumentException("Target method is not a delegate type.");
        }

        if (!InvokeRequired) {
            return targetDelegate.DynamicInvoke(args);
        }

        var callback = new InvokeDelegateTarget {
            Target = targetDelegate,
            Args = args
        };

        /* notify some class to invoke your delegate */
        Helper.ProcessDelegate(callback);
        /* while callback.Result == null {} or what ever check you do */

        return callback.Result;
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
    delegate void TryGetLocationB(IntPtr address, [Out] Vector3[] result);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
    delegate void TryGetLocationA(IntPtr address, out Vector3 result);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
    delegate bool IsEntityValidA(ref IntPtr entityAddress);


    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
    delegate bool IsEntityValidB(IntPtr[] entityAddress);
}
```

Comment: Being able to make a function pointer into a delegate doesn't mean the type is correct... since the CLR doesn't know the true type of the native pointer, it can't do any type checking at all.  So, do the delegates work if you actually call them?

Comment: @Ben Voigt 

Yes, the delegates do work when called. The above examples are the same signatures as I use in a real world application that works fine. The names are different is all.

The Helper.ProcessDelegate(callback); method is simply something that queues up the delegate target class instance into a concurrent queue, and signals the code I use to run in the main thread to process what is in the queue.

Comment: To be clear, all 4 methods return the same exact valid result and the functions being called is with in another unman-aged process module. This means both delegates below work nearly exactly the same, with the only difference being the signatures.

   [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
    delegate void TryGetLocationB(IntPtr address, [Out] Vector3[] result);

    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.ThisCall)]
    delegate void TryGetLocationA(IntPtr address, out Vector3 result);